# program does not output converted integer

Tags: c++, type-conversion, stringstream

I currently have a program in which I aim to create a function that can convert an integer into a string, here it is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string str(int x){
    std::stringstream convert;
    convert << x;
    return(convert.str());
}
int main () {
    int number = 10;
    std::string resulting_string;
    resulting_string = str(number);
    std::cout << "THE OUTPUT IS "<< resulting_string << std::endl;
    return(0);
}
```

however this does not output any result to the console. I would like it to output the string "10". I am relatively new to c++ so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your program is fine and should output 10. What compiler/platform?

Comment: See here: http://rextester.com/DEPB82289

Comment: I am using a Mac with xcode, does it make a difference what compiler you use?

Comment: Probably not, just trying to figure out why you don't see the output. Do you just run the program straight from the XCode IDE or something? Maybe the program is outputting 10 but it's doing it so quickly that you can't see the result.

Comment: Or maybe you're not looking at the correct place for output? Try doing this with obnoxious, eye-catching caps: `std::cout << "THE OUTPUT IS: " << resulting_string << std::endl;`  That should make it more noticeable.

Comment: Going to vote to close this as "can't reproduce" to avoid those kinds of, "Your program is fine" answers and protect you from potential down-votes -- but I'll try to help you out in the comments.

Comment: I have tried what you say but i just get "THE OUTPUT IS :

Comment: Thanks! sorry it was a bad question

Comment: That's really weird. you don't see any "10" there?

Comment: nope, is there anyway I can share the image of what I see?

Comment: can edit your question and upload an image

Comment: Try this code: http://rextester.com/XQPZ35806

Comment: To upload a pic, click the image icon when editing: http://i.stack.imgur.com/X3LSK.png